# r-cran-rquantlib does not install in R 3.6.1 and Debian 9

Tags: r, apt, cran, quantlib

I have had problems compiling `Quantlib` for Debian 9 and tried to install `r-cran-rquantlib` via `apt` from `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/`

I get the following error which I do not understand since I have both Rcpp and zoo already installed.

```
$ sudo apt install r-cran-rquantlib 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rquantlib : Depends: r-cran-rcpp (>= 0.11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: r-cran-zoo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is this a version mismatch problem? `r-cran-rquantlib` installs fine in Debian 10

Comment: What versions of `r-cran-rcpp` and `r-cran-zoo` are currently installed? Are the installed versions recent-enough?

Comment: Please post with sufficient detail in the `r-sig-debian` list.  Johannes, who looks after the backport, reads the list.  I, as author/maintainer of RQuantLib and r-cran-rquantlib, can onlu assure you that it works in all the mainline versions of Debian and Ubuntu.  There could be something inconsistent with the packport, or you could be lacking another repo (as the Rcpp and zoo messages indicate).

Comment: @r2evans Rcpp (1.0.2) and zoo (1.8-6) are installed via R and not apt.@Dirk Eddelbuettel I don't know how to post to r-sig.debian. Which additional details would one require?

Comment: ECII, I suggest you do your due-research for that one: (1) if you google [`r-sig.debian`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNScu3_gwSIHjUiRpq9n6zH8QHJhcA%3A1569460328730&ei=aBCMXdCSLKGc_QbXhYe4DQ&q=+r-sig.debian&oq=+r-sig.debian&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30l3.1428.1428..1871...0.1..0.339.339.3-1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.t48FcttzgDk&ved=0ahUKEwjQ5oerp-3kAhUhTt8KHdfCAdcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5), it will show you a link for (2) the [R-SIG-Debian Info Page](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian), which has a link for *"To post a message to all the list members"* ...